# field extension Q(∛2) of Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Perform each of the indicated operations in the field extension Q(∛2) of Q

Find the product (3+2∛2-5∛4).(1-∛2+3∛4) and find the multiplicative inverse of 2-∛2+∛4 .

please,I want help with that how can I find the product and  multiplicative inverse of field extension I did search for explanation for that but without useful.

Comment: Let $u = 2^{1/3}$. For the product you want to simplify, express each factor in terms of $u$, then multiply the polynomials (with u as a variable), but simplify the monomials in the product by replacing 
$$u^3\text{ by }2$$
$$u^4 = (u^3)u\text{ by }2u$$
$$\text{etc.}$$

Comment: For the inverse part, use the "$u$" variable as in the previous hint, but use undetermined rational coefficients $a,b,c$ for the result, setting the fraction in question to $au^2 + bu + c$. Then cross-multiply, simplify the powers of $u$, get everything on one side, and collect the terms in terms of the basis $1,u,u^2$. That yields $3$ equations in the $3$ unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: Also, aren't you using a textbook? If so, there's probably a worked-out example similar to this one.

Comment: @quasi, thanks for your note ,it is so helpful ,my book does not have any example like that because this topic outside of our requirement book.

Comment: @quasi,how about of it likes that (2-∛2+∛4)^3 do I have to simplify it like(2-∛2+∛4)*(2-∛2+∛4)*(2-∛2+∛4) and do like your hint above ?

Comment: Yes. Switch to "$u$"-form immediately (to maintain sanity), and proceed to multiply the polynomials, always simplifying powers of $u$ with exponent more than $2$, as soon as they arise.